# How can I make a generic Clone factory method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following **classes**:

```
public abstract class Item
{
    //...
}

public class Customer : Item
{
    //...
}

public class Address : Item
{      
    //...
}
```

I want to be able to create exact **clones** using a custom **reflection** class like this:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
ItemReflector irCustomer = new ItemReflector(customer);
Customer customerClone = irCustomer.GetClone<Customer>();
```

But I'm having trouble with the **syntax** of the GetClone method:

```
public class ItemReflector
{
    private Item item;

    public ItemReflector(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Item GetClone<T>()
    {
        T clonedItem = new T();
        //...manipulate the clonedItem with reflection...
        return clonedItem;
    }
}
```

**What do I have to change to the above GetClone() method so that it works?**

Comment: Look at my answer on [Why no ICloneable<T> ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536349/why-no-icloneablet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `new` constraint if you want to be able to instantiate `T`:

```
public Item GetClone<T>() where T: new()
{
    T clonedItem = new T();
    //...manipulate the clonedItem with reflection...
    return clonedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `GetClone()` is returning `Item` then presumably the constraint is that `T` is a sub class of `Item`.

Also since `ItemReflector` doesn't seem to need state `GetClone()` should be `static`.