# Deep copy of List<T>

Tags: c#, deep-copy

I'm trying to make a deep copy of a generic list, and am wondering if there is any other way then creating the copying method and actually copying over each member one at a time. I have a class that looks somewhat like this:

```
public class Data
{            
    private string comment;
    public string Comment
    {
        get { return comment; }
        set { comment = value; }
    }

    private List<double> traceData;
    public List<double> TraceData
    {
        get { return traceData; }
        set { traceData = value; }
    }
}
```

And I have a list of the above data, i.e `List<Data>`. What I'm trying to do is plot a trace data of the subset of List onto a graph, possibly with some scaling or sweeping on the data. I obviously don't need to plot everything in the list because they don't fit into the screen.

I initially tried getting the subset of the list using the `List.GetRange()` method, but it seems that the underneath `List<double>` is being shallow copied instead of deep copied. When I get the subset again using List.GetRange(), I get previously modified data, not the raw data retrieved elsewhere.

Can anyone give me a direction on how to approach this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Skeet edited but didn't know the answer? (8-O

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what would be a "Deep copy" of a `List<double>`?  It's a list of numbers, it's not like a list of Button classes or something that has members that might need to be copied?

Comment: I assume that he means he wants to make a deep copy of each `Data` object, implying that he needs to copy the list rather than just copy the reference.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusing words. Is there a way to deep copy only a setset of the List<Data> object? Thanks.

Comment: `Data.TraceData.GetRange()` creates a copy of the specified subset - is that an option? (Here it doesn't matter that `GetRange` creates a shallow copy since doubles are value types.)

Comment: I need get call the GetRange() on List<Data>, which then would hopefully deep-copy the traceData underneath. I am looking into more details from the answers given. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: A "deep copy" of a List<double> would be a List<double> with a new array of data elements containing the same numbers as were present in the original.  Note that merely deriving a class from List<T>, and having an object of that class call MemberwiseClone on itself, will not produce a usable List<T>, even if T is a value type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idiomatic way to approach this in C# is to implement [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) on your `Data`, and write a `Clone` method that does the deep copy (and then presumably a `Enumerable.CloneRange` method that can clone part of your list at once.) There isn't any built-in trick or framework method to make it easier than that.

Unless memory and performance are a real concern, I suggest that you try hard to redesign it to operate on immutable `Data` objects, though, instead.  It'll wind up much simpler.

Comment: +1: immutable is really the only way to go :) If the user doesn't need indexed access to the `List<double>`, then a simple immutable stack is more than adequate enough.

Comment: [IClonable is pretty much considered a bad idea these days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536349/why-no-icloneablet)

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
    public static object DeepCopy(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        Type type = obj.GetType();

        if (type.IsValueType || type == typeof(string))
        {
            return obj;
        }
        else if (type.IsArray)
        {
            Type elementType = Type.GetType(
                 type.FullName.Replace("[]", string.Empty));
            var array = obj as Array;
            Array copied = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, array.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                copied.SetValue(DeepCopy(array.GetValue(i)), i);
            }
            return Convert.ChangeType(copied, obj.GetType());
        }
        else if (type.IsClass)
        {

            object toret = Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType());
            FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {
                object fieldValue = field.GetValue(obj);
                if (fieldValue == null)
                    continue;
                field.SetValue(toret, DeepCopy(fieldValue));
            }
            return toret;
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown type");
    }
```

Thanks to DetoX83 [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38270/Deep-copy-of-objects-in-C) on code project.

Comment: Almost flawless. But as it was in my case, you have arrays of objects outside either mscorlib or the current assembly, you will need to use `elementType = Type.GetType(type.AssemblyQualifiedName.Replace("[]", string.Empty));`

Answer (score 5):

If IClonable way is too tricky for you. I suggest converting to something and back. It can be done with BinaryFormatter or a Json Converter like Servicestack.Text since it is the fastest one in .Net.

Code should be something like this:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
string json = mc.ToJson();
MyClass mcCloned = json.FromJson<MyClass>();
```

mcCloned will not reference mc.

Comment: ServiceStack use GPL. You may want to use Json.Net

Answer (score 3):

The most easiest (but dirty) way is to implement `ICloneable` by your class and use next extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Clone<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : ICloneable
{
    return collection.Select(item => (T)item.Clone());
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new List<Data> { new Data { Comment = "comment", TraceData = new List { 1, 2, 3 } };
var newList = list.Clone();
```

Comment: ICloneable is like a rash, start scratching and before you know it it's everywhere.

Comment: Should be noted that `item.Clone()` does not guarantee a deep copy, and the `.MemberwiseClone()` method create a shallow copy of internal members. See msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx

Comment: @Brad, @Juliet: That's why I called it dirty.

Answer (score 1):

another thing you can do is mark your class as `serializable` and use binary serialization.
Here is a working example

```
   public class Program
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class Test
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public Test()
            {

            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {   
            //create a list of 10 Test objects with Id's 0-10
            List<Test> firstList = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select( x => new Test { Id = x } ).ToList();
            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())

            {
                 var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                 binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, firstList); //serialize to stream
                 stream.Position = 0;
                 //deserialize from stream.
                 List<Test> secondList = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<Test>; 
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most of the time, I'd recommend implementing a deep copy by hand if you can since serialization isn't exactly known for its blazing speed. However, I've actually used this style in the past with *enormous* trees of mutable data, and it works just fine for practical use.

Comment: @Juliet, thanks, I was just providing an alternative solution to the ones that were already posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your objects immutable you don't need to worry about passing around copies of them, then you could do something like:

```
var toPlot = list.Where(d => d.ShouldBePlotted());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your collection is mutable, you need to implement the deep copy programmatically:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public List<double> TraceData { get; set; }

    public Data DeepCopy()
    {
        return new Data
        {
            Comment = this.Comment, 
            TraceData = this.TraceData != null
                ? new List<double>(this.TraceData)
                : null;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Comment` field can be shallow copied because its already an immutable class. You need to create a new list for `TraceData`, but the elements themselves are immutable and require no special handling to copy them.

> When I get the subset again using
>   List.GetRange(), I get previously
>   modified data, not the raw data
>   retrieved elsewhere.

Use your new `DeepCopy` method as such:

```
var pointsInRange = dataPoints
    .Select(x => x.DeepCopy())
    .GetRange(start, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DeepListCopy_testingSome
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
            List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

            //populate list1
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                list1.Add(1);
            }

            ///////
            Console.WriteLine("\n int in each list1 element is:\n");
            ///////

            foreach (int i in list1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" list1 elements: {0}", i);
                list2.Add(1);
            }

            ///////
            Console.WriteLine("\n int in each list2 element is:\n");
            ///////

            foreach (int i in list2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" list2 elements: {0}", i);
            }

            ///////enter code here

            for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count; i++)
            {
                list2[i] = 2;
            }



            ///////
            Console.WriteLine("\n Printing list1 and list2 respectively to show\n"
                            + " there is two independent lists,i e, two differens"
                            + "\n memory locations after modifying list2\n\n");
            foreach (int i in list1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Printing list1 elements: {0}", i);
            }

            ///////
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            ///////

            foreach (int i in list2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Printing list2 elements: {0}", i);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }//end of Static void Main
    }//end of class
}
```

Comment: Try using a collection of objects that are not primitives. Then your example will not work. Edit: Well now I see you are not even populating list 2 with list 1! This is not related to the question..

Answer (score 0):

One **quick** and **generic** way to deeply serialize an object is to use [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). The following extension method allows serializing of a list of any arbitrary objects, but is able to skip Entity Framework navigation properties, since these may lead to circular dependencies and unwanted data fetches.

**Method**

```
public static List<T> DeepClone<T>(this IList<T> list, bool ignoreVirtualProps = false)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    if (ignoreVirtualProps)
    {
        settings.ContractResolver = new IgnoreNavigationPropsResolver();
        settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
        settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }

    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, settings);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(serialized);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var clonedList = list.DeepClone();
```

By default, JSON.NET serializes only public properties. If private properties must be also cloned, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107081/2780791) can be used.

This method allows for [quick (de)serialization](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/01/01/net-serialization-performance-comparison) of [complex hierarchies of objects](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm).