# Why is my variable of type List<Point> being changed even though I'm not using references?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a variable called `temp` which is of type `List<Point>`. For some reason, when I call `sanitize(temp)`, the variable `temp` seems to change. I know that the variable `temp` changes, because the output I get on `C:\out.bmp` is different if I include the `sanitize(temp)` line or not. The output I am getting from the messagebox is "temp was not changed."

```
List<Point> original = temp;
sanitize(temp);

if (temp.Equals(original)) {
    MessageBox.Show(@"temp was not changed.");
} else {
    MessageBox.Show(@"temp was changed.");
}

outputPointsOnBitmap(temp.ToArray(), ref windowBitmap, Color.Yellow);
windowBitmap.Save("C:\\out.bmp");
```

For the curious, here is more source code:

```
private void outputPointsOnBitmap(Point[] points, ref Bitmap bitmap, Color markerColor) {
    foreach (Point point in points) {
        bitmap.SetPixel(point.X, point.Y, markerColor);
    }
}

private List<Point> sanitize(List<Point> crossPoints) {
    SortedSet<int> indexesToDelete = new SortedSet<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < crossPoints.Count() - 1; i++) {
        if (Math.Abs(crossPoints[i + 1].X - crossPoints[i].X) <= 5 &&
            Math.Abs(crossPoints[i + 1].Y - crossPoints[i].Y) <= 5) {
            indexesToDelete.Add(i);
            indexesToDelete.Add(i + 1);
        }
    }

    foreach (int i in indexesToDelete.Reverse()) {
        crossPoints.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    return crossPoints;
}
```

This is driving me nuts.

Comment: You *are* using references. You are passing by *value* yes. But the value you are passing is a *reference* to your list.

Comment: @aquinas: How do I know if I am using references to objects or the objects themselves? I suppose that all Lists are just references to objects? What if I have a variable of type `Point`. Is that an object or a reference to an object?

Comment: C# has reference types and value types. You should read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do:

```
List<Point> original = temp;
```

You make the variable `original` refer to the list that `temp` refers to.

So any changes that `sanitize` makes to `temp` are also visible in `original`. `temp.Equals(original)` returns true because they are the same object. If you want `original` to be a new list with the same items as `temp`, construct a new `List` object:

```
List<Point> original = new List<Point>(temp);
```

You say you're not using references, but [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a reference type because it doesn't inherit from [`ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - when you assign or pass it you're always using references.

Here's a good breakdown of the difference between value and reference types in .Net:
http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

As Jordy Langen points out, `temp.Equals(original)` will always return false now, because the the two lists are different objects (and that's what [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) looks at for reference types). If you want to see whether the `sanitize` function changed the list at all, you can use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (temp.SequenceEqual(original)) {
    MessageBox.Show(@"temp was not changed.");
} else {
    MessageBox.Show(@"temp was changed.");
}
```

Comment: The Equals method will always return false now.

Comment: Everything inherits from object, not only reference types.

Comment: True. I'll change that to say it *doesn't* inherit from ValueType.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `original` to not change, do this:

```
List<Point> original = new List<Point>(temp);
sanitize(temp);
```

That will create a new `List<Point>` with the contents of `temp`. Otherwise, `List<Point> original = temp` just creates a new reference (original) to the same memory location which contains your list (temp).

In order to check if your 2 lists are different in your case, check their Count (since Equals will always return false).

```
if( temp.Count != original.Count ) 
{
    // now you know that some items were removed in your sanitize method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp` changes because you're passing a reference to it into `sanitize` which is assigned to the `crossPoints` variable. Because it's passed by reference any changes to `crossPoints` (via the call to `RemoveAt`) also affect `temp` since they point to the same list.

When you say:

```
List<Point> original = temp;
```

You're making `temp` and `original` refence the same list. It does not create a copy of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Temp and original are not objects, they are references to objects, in your case, they both reference the same list object. Normally, equals does reference comparison on objects, so it will say they are equal. Either way you are comparing a list object to itself. In your sanitize method, you change the same list.

Answer (score 1):

It is being modified because it is being passed as a reference, so the delete operation is actually being performed on the same reference the temp variable holds.  you may be the desired result if you do the following:

```
private List<Point> sanitize(List<Point> crossPoints) {
    var workset = new List<Point>(crosspoints);
    SortedSet<int> indexesToDelete = new SortedSet<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < workset.Count() - 1; i++) {
        if (Math.Abs(workset[i + 1].X - workset[i].X) <= 5 &&
            Math.Abs(workset[i + 1].Y - workset[i].Y) <= 5) {
            indexesToDelete.Add(i);
            indexesToDelete.Add(i + 1);
        }
    }

    foreach (int i in indexesToDelete.Reverse()) {
        workset.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    return workset;
}
```

of course keep in mind this is an O(n) operation since you are making a copy of the references in the list

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
List<Point> original = temp;
```

`original` does now have the **same** reference as `temp`. Meaning: All changes you apply to the `temp` variable are also applied to the `original` variable because they share the **same reference**.

You should create a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226747/deep-copy-of-listt) of the list to make this work. One more thing:

The `Equals` will always return false if you use a deep copy. Equals check if the **references are equal**. You most probable need to do check based on the items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your list `temp` is an object, and objects are passed by reference, so your sanitize method is changing the underlying object.

However, your output says it's not changed because you assign `original = temp`, meaning that your variable `original` is a pointer to the same object as your variable `temp`, so when you compare the two they are equal, even though the object has actually changed since before it was passed to sanitize.