# LINQ retains unwanted data binding

Tags: c#, linq, list

Let's make a variable named **i_Changes** of type `List<List<int>>` which has the following values:

```
[1] = 1,2
[2] = 3,4,6
[3] = 4,8,15
```

This Variable is stored in a class **myClass** which looks like this:

```
Public Class myClass
{
    public DateTime selectedDate {get; set}
    public List<List<int>> i_Changes {get;set;}
}
```

Now we have another variable named **i_Holder** of type `List<List<List<int>>>` which is supposed to hold values of i_Changes (that means after every iteration I want to store exact numbers from i_Changes so that later (after process) I can show them all to user in a Grid.

What I do after every iteration, to store new variable is the following:

```
i_Holder.Add(myClass.Select(n=>n.i_Changes).ToList();
```

I found out that when I add items to my list like this, they keep binding with the original **i_Changes**, which means that after every iteration (when values under i_Changes change), all values under i_Holder change accordingly -> that means I have list of n items with exact same values such as current **i_Changes**.

How can I solve this problem?

Also, if you believe that `List<List<List<int>>>` is not a good idea, please feel free to correct me, as it was the only thing what I could think of.

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I found out that when I create new `List<List<int>>` and manually copy each values to that list, then binding is lost; however I believe it is not the best thing to do (create new List after every iteration). Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Please share more code for your questions.

Comment: code that does the operation has more than 600 lines. At the end of iteration I do exactly this (add new values to the list), so there is really no other relevant code

Comment: for `i_Holder`,I suggest you use `List<int>`. and `i_Holder=i_Holder.Contact(myClass.SelectMany(n=>n.i_Changes).ToList());`

Comment: what does .Contact stand for? I cannot find it among LINQ commands; also Select many would simply put results in 1D array if I am not mistaken; but I need to keep the structure of my array

Comment: Your sample code is really strange : `i_Holder.Add(myClass.Select(n=>n.i_Changes).ToList();` first it doesn't compile, secondly if `myClass` is an instance of `myClass`, you can't do a `Select` on it : it's not an `IEnumerable<myClass>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are holding a list of references to the same object, so when the object changes, you will see that change in every item in your list.

You need to create a new list containing the desired values each time, like this:

```
i_Holder.Add(myClass
    .Select(n => n.i_Changes.Select(j => new List<int>(j)).ToList()).ToList());
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! However do you think that this is a good practice, creating new List every time? Shouldn't I create something different for this purpose? Or apply different method?

Comment: Well.. you need to make a copy of all the `int` values however you do it, so using a new `List` is probably no worse than any other approach!

Answer (score 1):

In C# lists are passed by reference so i think this is the reason you getting this issue. in order to avoid this you have to do deep copy of your lists, prior to adding them.

You can read about deep clone of the lists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226747/deep-copy-of-listt)