# What is the quickest way to create an independent duplicate of a list (not the objects in it)?

Tags: c#, list

Say I have a ListA. I want to make a duplicate ListB so when I use `ListB.Remove(SomeItem);` it would not affect the listA.

The list items should refer to the same objects.

Since this is being used in a loop it is important to use least resource demanding approach. But I don't know how to do this in most efficient way.

Comment: Are the objects reference types, or value types?

Comment: I think the LINQ library supports a function that is called Copy(). But basically you can just create new List () and then iteratively add each element in ListA to the new list. Or just juse newList.AddRange(listA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep copy of List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226747/deep-copy-of-listt)

Comment: What should happen when you modify `someItem` instead of deleting it? Should the change be reflected in both lists?

Comment: It's a duplicate question... Anyways. Why don't you create two lists initially and add items to list 'B' along with list 'A'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, no one seems to be looking for a specialized `List<T>` method (which by definition should have an optimal implementation), and there is one called [GetRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx) which according to the documentation

> Creates a shallow copy of a range of elements in the source List<T>.

So creating a shallow copy of the whole source list would be something like this

```
var shallowClone = originalList.GetRange(0, originalList.Count);
```

**P.S.** Of course the difference in performance from the most concise

```
var shallowClone = originalList.ToList();
```

and not so concise

```
var shallowClone = new List<MyLongListItemType>(originalList);
```

will be negligible.

So I would personally prefer `ToList`version, and at the same time will remember to **not** call `ToList` in my code without a need (which I've seen in many places) because of the copy behavior of that method.

Answer (score 7):

You want a shallow clone, which you can do simply using [this `List<T>` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var shallowClone = new List(originalList);
```

Note that the implementation of this constructor checks if `originalList` supports the `Count` property, and if it does it uses it to pre-size the list to avoid unnecessary memory allocations. This makes it pretty optimal:

```
_items = new T[count];
c.CopyTo(_items, 0);
_size = count;
```

However, I've looked at the implementation of `Enumerable<T>.ToList()` and all it does is call the `List<T>` constructor above.

So this code does pretty much exactly the same thing (and will run at the same speed):

```
var shallowClone = originalList.ToList();
```

Comment: The easiest and simplest way!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call `ListB.ToList()` which will create a new list from `ListB` sharing the same elements. Changes to the element-SET of `ListB` are not reflected in `A`, however if you change any element it is reflected in both lists.

Comment: Thanks Him; This is a very good answer. But there might be a quicker way.

Comment: I dount there is a QUICKER way as all this implementation does is iterating the first list and creating a new list from it. However there is a neater way as suggested by Matthew.

Comment: You don't need the `.Select()` btw. With the `Select()` this will be significantly slower.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I wasn´t sure if `ToList` will eventually cast the instance to `list` if it already is one. Yiu may be right however.

Comment: This is actually now one character shorter than using the `List<T>` constructor directly. :)

Answer (score 2):

In your case u can use List Generic Method.
Add this method in your class.

```
public static List<T> Clone<T>(this List<T> myList)
{
    var newList = new List<T>(myList.Capacity);
    newList.AddRange(myList);
    return newList;
}
```