# Why modification in Arraylist copy, modifies the original?

Tags: java, arraylist, cloneable

I am trying to copy the contents of an ArrayList to another and change the contents of copy. I don't want this to be reflected in the original.

I checked on SO and made changes accordingly, still the same issue. Can someone help? I am sharing the code below:

```
private ArrayList<CustVoiceListObject> FilterApprovedWorkFromList() {

        ArrayList<CustVoiceListObject> arrayListCopy = new ArrayList<>(arrayListCustVoice);

            for(int i =0; i<arrayListCopy.get(position).getPackageArray().size();i++)
            {
                if(!arrayListCopy.get(position).getPackageArray().get(i).getPackageApproved().equals("Y"))
                {
                    arrayListCopy.get(position).getPackageArray().remove(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        return arrayListCopy;
    }
```

While debugging, when it is about to return, I check the original arraylist `arrayListCustVoice` but this is also modified similar `arrayListCopy`

What am I missing?

**UPDATE** [Following the suggestions][This questions hence is not duplicate!]

This is my modified code:

```
 private ArrayList<CustVoiceListObject> FilterApprovedWorkFromList() {

        ArrayList<CustVoiceListObject> arrayListCopy = (ArrayList<CustVoiceListObject>) arrayListCustVoice.clone();

            for(int i =0; i<arrayListCopy.get(position).getPackageArray().size();i++)
            {
                if(!arrayListCopy.get(position).getPackageArray().get(i).getPackageApproved().equals("Y"))
                {
                    arrayListCopy.get(position).getPackageArray().remove(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        return arrayListCopy;
    }
```

In fact I have implemented Cloneable to my original class, still I am facing the same problem.

**Update 2** [Research Conclusion]

I came across this [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/)

In my case, there are 2 classes. The 2nd is subset of first. Pasting below:

```
public class CustVoiceListObject implements Cloneable {

    private String txtSource, txtCustComment, txtCustOk, txtRepeat;

    private int numberOfPackages, complaintSerial;

    private ArrayList<CustomerVoicePackageListObject> packageArray;

    private Double totalAmount;

   //getters & setters & constructors

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }


}
```

Class 2:

```
public class CustomerVoicePackageListObject implements Cloneable {

    public String packageCategory;
    public String packageName;
    public String partUsageFlag;
    public String laborUsageFlag;
    public String status;
    public String isApproved;

 //getters & setters & constructors

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

The `.clone()` must link to the `clone()` of the CLASS, not elsewhere. And if it correctly does, it will provoke for taking measure to address the exception as per my implementing the clone() in each individual class.

So this is what I did, modified that for loop to this:

```
 private CustVoiceListObject FilterApprovedWorkFromList() {

//Observe the change here. It's no more ArrayList, it's Class type
        CustVoiceListObject arrayListCopy = null;
        try {
            arrayListCopy = (CustVoiceListObject) arrayListCustVoice.get(position).clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i =0; i<arrayListCopy.getPackageArray().size();i++)
            {
                if(!arrayListCopy.getPackageArray().get(i).getPackageApproved().equals("Y"))
                {
                    arrayListCopy.getPackageArray().remove(i); //this is ArrayList<ClassType>. Nested class objects.
                    arrayListCopy.setTxtCustOk("OKOK"); //within the class
                    i--;
                }
            }
        return arrayListCopy;
    }
```

The result was the changes within the packageArray reflected in both (failure) BUT, changes in txtCustOk within the basic class, changed in copy, not in original (success). That means, problem is in cloning with ArrayList

So deep cloning requires satisfaction of following rules:

> 1.No need to separately copy primitives.
>
> 2.All the member classes in  original class should support cloning and in clone method of original  class in context should call
>   super.clone() on all member classes.
>
> 3.If any member class does not support cloning then in clone method, one  must create a new instance of that member class and copy all its 
>   attributes one by one to new member class object. This new member 
>   class object will be set in cloned object.

So my aim is to get rid of ArrayList and shift those elements to this class. This is painful. Looking for an easy alternative.

Comment: replace this line and check

ArrayList<CustVoiceListObject> arrayListCopy = new ArrayList<>(arrayListCustVoice);

by

ArrayList<CustVoiceListObject> arrayListCopy = arrayListCustVoice;

Comment: That was my first attempt. Failed.

Comment: I don't consider the categorization of this question as duplicate, apt. None of those solutions works here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your elements of the original `ArrayList` are reference values so you just copy the references to those objects but not the objects themselves (which seem to be another kind of arrays).

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226747/deep-copy-of-listt) question which essentially deals with the same kind of problem.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is related to JAVA. Concept surely is the same.

Comment: In other words: the same object is placed is both lists, and changing that object will be seen in both lists. Maybe the object itself must be cloned, or on change a new object should replace the original object.

Answer (score 0):

The copy operation copied the original list - but not the elements of the list.

That is, if `oldList` had the following `Person` objects:

> `oldList`: `John`, `Jane`, `Jude`, `Joe`

And you copied `oldList` to `newList`:

> `oldList`: `John`, `Jane`, `Jude`, `Joe`
>   `newList`: `John`, `Jane`, `Jude`, `Joe`

And then deleted `John` from `newList`:

> `oldList`: `John`, `Jane`, `Jude`, `Joe`
>   `newList`: `Jane`, `Jude`, `Joe`

you can see that they are two distinct lists. But you're **not** changing the lists, you're changing the objects *inside* the list. If `Joe`'s name got changed to `Jim`, you'd have:

> `oldList`: `John`, `Jane`, `Jude`, `Jim`
>   `newList`: `Jane`, `Jude`, `Jim`

You have only done what is called a "shallow" copy. You want to do a "deep" copy, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents).

---

**Edit** (to "Update 2" in question)

Your research didn't go far enough, I'm afraid. In your (new) Class 1:

```
public class CustVoiceListObject implements Cloneable {

    // ints, Doubles, Strings

    private ArrayList<CustomerVoicePackageListObject> packageArray;

    //getters & setters & constructors

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

you simply returned `super.clone()` - letting Java do all the work for you. This basically does the shallow copy that's causing all your problems! You might as well not have made the object `ICloneable`. What you missed was that `int`s, `Double`s and even `String`s already copy successfully, so you don't need to clone them. But `ArrayList`s *don't* clone, so you need to help it along:

```
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    // First copy the easy stuff
    CustomerVoiceListObject cvlo = (CustomerVoiceListObject)super.clone();

    cvlo.packageArray = new ArrayList<CustomerVoicePackageListObject>(packageArray.size()); // Make sure it's the right size

    for (CustomerVoicePackageListObject cvplo: packageArray) {
        cvlo.packageArray.add(cvplo.clone());
    } // for
    return cvlo;
} // clone()
```

Comment: I concluded the same. Do you have reference for Java?

Comment: I updated my answer with a different link for Java - although that does require that your class implements the `ICloneable` interface

Comment: Please check the update I have added and let know

Comment: @Krsna I have edited my answer in response to your Updates

Comment: Thank you, I will try and let know as this was an important thing to understand, although I removed this concept for the time being in order to meet a deadline.

Comment: clone() has protected access in "java.lang.Object"
Appears at the last appearance of clone() - cvplo.clone()